# Vim - Delete line range without folds affecting it

Tags: vim, neovim

I need to programmatically delete a range of lines, which is defined by two variables. This is possible with `:d` (e.g. `exec l:begin l:end 'd _'`), but this does not do what is intended when folds are in place.

Quoting the vim help:

> For Ex commands that work on buffer lines the range is adjusted to always
>   start at the first line of a closed fold and end at the last line of a closed fold.

I've managed to work around this with `:foldopen` on the range, but is there a better way?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could include sample input, i.e. a fragment of your input (code) file.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the input file looks something like (assuming `set foldmethod=marker`):

```
{{{                                                                             
1                                                                               
2                                                                               
3                                                                               
4                                                                               
5                                                                               
}}}                                                                             
7
8
9
```

and we want to remove lines with `3` and `4`, then the proposed solution `exec begin','end 'd _'` with `let begin = 4 | let end = 5` would work. However, if the fold is closed:

```
+--  7 lines: ----------------------------------------------------------
7
8
9
```

you need something like:

```
exec 'folddoc '.begin.','.end.'s/.*//g'                                         
exec 'folddoc '.begin.','.end.'s/^$\n//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `:foldopen`, you can temporarily disable folding. In an interactive session, I'd do this with `zi` ... `zi` or `zn` ... `zN`.

In a script / plugin, I'd use the corresponding Ex commands in a `try..catch`:

```
let l:save_foldenable = &l:foldenable
setlocal nofoldenable
try
    exec l:begin l:end 'd _
finally
    let &l:foldenable = l:save_foldenable
endtry
```